# Why does my Codeblock only display output for less than second..?

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks

I installed Codeblock a week ago and have not changed any setting. I created a simple console application and when I clicked build and run it display my output for like milisecond and disappear... It used to stay forever until I exit it. Anyone know why is this happening? In the Build log tab it says "Process terminated with status 0 (0minnutes, 0 seconds)

Comment: Let me guess; you are using MS-Windows, when you run the application, the console opens and closes immediatly afterward? That's because console applications are meant to be executed by typing the programm name into a running console window, not by clicking on the application icon. For debugging purposes, you can add some code at the end that waits for a key press.

Comment: Does your output appears and disappears in about 0.1s, I guess you need to look for the output window in your codeblocks application.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any problem actually, neither in your Codeblocks Application nor in your code, But codeblocks **doesn't wait for you** to close its console window manually, It **automatically** does it.

You've 3 ways, choose that suits you better

1. Go to Menu Bar and toggle '**show output window**'
2. Alternatively you can append a C++ code that waits for an event to happen, so that you may get enough time to watch your Output.
   You can use the code which I've given below
3. It will be definitely good if you choose to see your output message through **debugging**(Step Over).
    It will also improve your debugging skills.

If you want to choose second approach then append following code in your application

```
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    // After your code - write
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Note:-** I believe you're using codeblocks on Windows Platform, this code will work fine on windows, but `<conio.h>`
won't be available to you if you want to port your program from Windows to Linux

I'll recommend you to give them preference in this order **`[3 > 1 > 2]`**

Answer (score 2):

## for those who may encounter this error:

all you need to do to make the console not dissapear is this:

- go to project properties.
- click on build targets
- there is an option below console application  "pause when execution ends"
- check it and you are good to go!

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
#include <iostream>
//...other includes....
int main()
{
   /*Your Code */
   //...
   std::cin.ignore(); //wait for Enter, will makes the console to stay.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be clicking on the red arrow, however click on the "build an run" arrow instead, which has a little cog and a green arrow.

Comment: Please do not answer with a comment/question. Understandably, your rep is too low to comment, but that still does not mean answers should be used to make comments as an alternative. It would be preferable if you deleted this.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution if you are copying and pasting input:** For me, the issue was that I was copying and pasting my input file from the web. Presumably, this *copied some invisible characters*, such as a return, which my program registered as the user having pressed any key to continue. The solution I used was to *download the file to my computer*, then *run my program in command prompt*, piping the input into the .exe file in the following manner:

```
C:\Project Directory> myProgram.exe < myInputFile.txt
```

Many of my professors recommend running programs from the command line, and I advise using this tactic as it is quick and lets you skip manual typing. Also, you can save the output of your program to a desired file, rather than having it print on the command line, by doing the following:

```
C:\Project Directory> myProgram.exe < myInputFile.txt > programOutput.txt
```

Hope this helps.